# What does it mean if campaign member record has no leadId or ContactId?

Tags: campaign-member

What does it mean if campaign member record has no leadId or ContactId? I am seeing some records like this in my org. I am unable to update those records.

Comment: you might have campaignMembers as Accounts enabled